# nuxtjs onesignal configuration

Tags: nuxt.js, onesignal

I followed the procedure https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/modules/onesignal.html#async-functions
form there official documentation website, but it didnt setup

```
this.$OneSignal.push(() => {
      this.$OneSignal.isPushNotificationsEnabled((isEnabled) => {
        if (isEnabled) {
          console.log('Push notifications are enabled!')
        } else {
          console.log('Push notifications are not enabled yet.')
        }
      })
    })
```

error: cannot read property push of undefined

Did i miss something that needs to setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try accessing it using the global window method:

```
// Using window and array form
window.OneSignal.push(['addListenerForNotificationOpened', (data) => {
console.log('Received NotificationOpened:', data )}
]);
```